# How to catch Exception thrown in a method invoked by using MethodInfo.Invoke?

Tags: c#, exception, reflection, try-catch, invoke

I have the following codes:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;

namespace TestInvoke
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      Method1();
      Console.WriteLine();
      Method2();
    }

    static void Method1()
    {
      try
      {
        MyClass m = new MyClass();
        m.MyMethod( -3 );
      }
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
        Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
      }
    }

    static void Method2()
    {
      try
      {
        string className = "TestInvoke.MyClass";
        string methodName = "MyMethod";
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
        object myObject = assembly.CreateInstance( className );
        MethodInfo methodInfo = myObject.GetType().GetMethod( methodName );
        methodInfo.Invoke( myObject, new object[] { -3 } );
      }
      catch ( Exception e )
      {
        Console.WriteLine( e.Message );
      }

    }
  }

  public class MyClass
  {
    public void MyMethod( int x )
    {
      if ( x < 0 )
        throw new ApplicationException( "Invalid argument " + x );

      // do something
    }

  }
}
```

**Method1** and **Method2** both execute **MyClass.MyMethod**, but **Method1** outputs:

```
Invalid argument -3
```

while **Method2** outputs:

```
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Could we modify **Method2** so it could catch the exception as in **Method1**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the `InnerException`. In .NET reflection will wrap the exception - which can be useful for knowing how the exception was called. See the inner exception property has the exception you are looking for.
[image: stack trace]

So to have the same exception just call `Console.WriteLine(e.InnerException.Message)` instead.